# Does unbricking Asus RT N16 Router require extra hardware?

Tags: router, firmware, tomato

I bought a new Asus RT N16 router today. I am going to load Tomato USB on the router. If I brick the router during this process, do I need any extra hardware to unbrick the router? I read somewhere that you need to connect to the router using serial cable to unbrick some routers. Is that the case with N16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I can't tell for your model or the router software but I have a Linksys Wag200G and sometimes I use a special serial cable to unbrick the router. It's not very often but it's extremly useful to have it. Here is some link about JTAG interface and cable:

1. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/JTAG_pinouts#Asus_RT-N16
2. http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php?threads/rt-n16-jtag.31879/

You need to buy some cheap electronics and solder. Disclaimer: You need some experience with soldierung it's very likely you brick your device. I've bricked one Linksys WAG200 by wrong soldering and also I think you will loose warranty and so on. Do it at your own risk!

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide more details about the serial cable. Do I need to solder the cable, or can I connect it directly?

Comment: @JoyceBabu - If you don't already know how to use a JTAG cable I suggest you do your research.  If you follow the directions loading the firmware won't brick your router.